# Is there any prime $p$ such that $(p-1)!+1=p^m$

Tags: number-theory

According to Wilson Theorem, we know that 
$$p\mid(p-1)!+1$$
for $p\in\mathbb{P}$. Also, we have

> $(2-1)!+1=2^1\\
> (3-1)!+1=3^1\\
> (5-1)!+1=5^2$

I guess there is no such prime $p$ satisfying $(p-1)!+1=p^m$ besides $2,3,5$. But I have no idea to prove it. Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: *Table[IntegerQ[Log[Prime[n],(Prime[n]-1)!+1]],{n,1,10000}]* in Mathematica gives that only the first three primes within the first 10.000 primes fulfill the relation.

Comment: At least, a heuristic argument suggests that there should be a finite number of such $p$. By Stirling's formula, $m$ would have to be somewhat less than $p$, but not by a lot. So the probability of an arbitrary number $p$ having this property should be *very* roughly of the order of $p^{-p}$. Since $\sum p^{-p}$ is finite, and in fact quite small, there should be just a few examples – prime or non-prime. Unless, of course, there is some good reason for the opposite.

Comment: If we eliminate (p-1) from both sides of (p-1)! = [p-1][1 + p + P^2 ..+P^(m-1)]. we get (p-2)! =[1 + p + P^2 ..+P^(m-1)] . Now if p > 5 . Then lhs = 0 mod (p-1) while rhs = m mod (p-1). This says that p-1 divides m. But P^(p-1) >>(p-1)! for large p, thus they cant differ by 1 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we eliminate $(p-1)$ from both sides of $(p-1)! = (p-1)(1 + p + p^2 ..+p^{m-1})$. we get $(p-2)! =(1 + p + p^2 ..+p^{m-1})$ . Now if $p > 5$, then $LHS = 0 \mod (p-1)$ as $p-1 = 2 * \frac{p-1}{2}$ while $RHS = m \mod (p-1)$. This says that $p-1$ divides $m$. But $p^{p-1} >>(p-1)!$ for large $p$, thus they cant differ by 1